# When $cn+d$ divides $an+b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Suppose that we have chosen $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I would like to know, whether, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$, such $an+b$ is divisible by $cn+d$.

> Find a criterion for $a,b,c,d$, so that $cn+d$ divides $an+b$ for some n.

For example, let's take $6n+5$ and $n+2$. From the one hand i know that divisibility holds for $n=5$, but from the other hand it is hard to tell it a priori, without checking following numbers.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Hint: if so, by *eliminating* $\,n,\,$ it divides $\,c(an+b)-a(cn+d) = bc-ad\,$ (and conversely if $\,\gcd(c,d)=1).\,$ I'm sure this is a dupe, but I couldn't find it in a very quick search. Maybe later...